# Laravel5: Can't delete from DB

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is in controller `MessagesController`:

```
public function destroy(Messages $id)
{
    \DB::delete(
            'DELETE FROM messages WHERE id=' . $id
        );
    return redirect()->route('messages.index')->with('message', 'Deleted.');
}
```

This is routes.php:

```
Route::delete('messages.destroy', ['as' => 'messages.destroy', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@destroy']);
```

This is view file:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route'=>['messages.destroy',$message->id],'method'=>'DELETE')) !!}
{!! Form::button('Delete',['class'=>'btn btn-danger','type'=>'submit']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

So, I have an error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[]' at line 1
>   (SQL: DELETE FROM messages WHERE id=[])

I understand that there is no id going to controller. How to solve this?

P.S. Also, tried like this in controller:

```
public function destroy(Messages $message)
{
    $message->delete();
    return redirect()->route('messages.index')->with('message', 'Deleted.');
}
```

It's just showing message `Deleted`. but it's not deleting a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what i'm doing:

routes/web.php :

```
Route::resource('products', 'Products');
```

controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
        Product::destroy($id);
        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
}
```

View:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['products.destroy', $product->id],'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: and the path in browser is "/messages.destroy?16". 16 is id of the object.

Comment: It might be because you send it through as an array. Try it without the array in your blade view: 

{!! Form::open('route'=>['messages.destroy',$message->id],'method'=>'DELETE') !!}
       {!! Form::button('Delete',['class'=>'btn btn-danger','type'=>'submit']) !!}
   {!! Form::close() !!}

Comment: I have edited the answer, I am using this format in one of my applications. please try that?

Comment: Still isn't working. By the way what like is your controller and routes.php?

Answer (score 0):

Try this route:

```
Route::delete('messages.destroy/{id}', ['as' => 'messages.destroy', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@destroy']);
```

and this controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    Message::destroy($id);
    return redirect()->route('messages.index')->with('message', 'Deleted.');
}
```